# Complex firewall configuration - Symfony2 security

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

Here is the situation:

I currently have two existing firewalls -- namely `main` and `admin`. Somehow I need to add a third firewall for my shopping section.

My shop basically has these steps:

```
Select subscription -> user creation/login -> Capture billing information -> Review purchase -> Capture payment
```

New requirements are that if the user is not yet logged in, I need to capture user information and billing address **but not store it within the user repository** -- the client's argument is that this would stop from locking an email address to an account that possibly did not go through the whole purchase flow, thereby keeping the user from using that email address in the future should he decide to continue.

Here is the authentication flow I have in mind:

- I create a new firewall named `shop`.
- When user is not logged in, I redirect him to `shop/account/create`. This step will create a new order in the system, marked `initiated`. **This order will contain the user information provided, along with the session ID.** No actual user account is created.
- A custom authentication provider will check the session ID and look for an existing `initiated` order binded to it, and construct an authenticated token and a mocked user entity from the user information within the order.
- After the payment is captured, the system will create a new user in the data-store, with the appropriate subscriptions purchased.

I already prototyped the custom authentication provider, and here is my `security.yml`:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
          form_login:
              check_path: /user/login_check
              provider: fos_userbundle
              csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
              default_target_path: /user/home
          logout:
              invalidate_session: false
              path: /user/logout
              target: /
     admin:
          pattern: ^/admin
          form_login:
              login_path: /admin/login
              check_path: /admin/login_check
              provider: app_adminbundle
              csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
              default_target_path: /admin
          logout:
              invalidate_session: false
              path: /admin/logout
              target: /admin/login
     shop:
         pattern: ^/shop
         shop_auth: true
```

`shop_auth` is my custom authentication provider. (I have put up the implementation here: https://gist.github.com/bezhermoso/9305705)

My problem is that I don't know how to configure my firewall so that if the user is already logged in in the `main` firewall, my shop should simply allow him in without having to check his session ID against existing orders and simply create a new one.

How can I configure my firewall to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was looking at this the wrong way...

I was able to to implement a solution with the help of a friend. He pointed out that I do not need to create a separate firewall. Instead, just add my custom authentication provider (which is responsible for matching the current session to a pending order) to the `"main"` configuration and control authorization via custom attributes and a custom voter:

`security.yml`:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
          form_login:
              check_path: /user/login_check
              provider: fos_userbundle
              csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
              default_target_path: /user/home
          logout:
              invalidate_session: false
              path: /user/logout
              target: /
          shop_auth: true #Ta-da!

access_controls:
    - { path: /shop, [CAN_SHOP, ... ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really get your problem.
Maybe it will help to know you can set up a chain provider to log in from multiple 'providers':

```
providers:
  chain_provider:
     chain:
       providers: [shop_auth, main_provider]
  shop_auth:
     id: service.shop_auth
  main_provider: 
     id: fos_userbundle

firewalls:
  # ...
  shop:
    form_login:
       provider: chain_provider
```